# Motives and representations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, representation-theory

Assuming standard conjectures, the category of motives is equivalent to the category of representations of a certain group over $\mathbb Q$, but I don't understand the abstract construction.

Now, if we start with a nonsingular projective variety $X$ we get a motive $(X, \Delta_X, 0)$, so we should also get a representation $\rho$. I think it would help me to understand concretely what representation arises this way.

As far as I understood, the space of the representation should be $\bigoplus_{i=0}^{2 \dim(X)} H^i(X)$, and it should probably factor through some simpler group. I would be grateful to anyone explainig me how to explicitely build/ describe $\rho$ from $X$.

Answer (score 5):

(Here we assume that $k\subset\mathbb{C}$).

Ok, so we assume the standard conjectures, in particular that the numerical equivalence coincide with the homological one. Then the category of motives $M(k)$ is abelian semi-simple and we have a functor, the Betti-realization : $H_B:M(k)\to \mathbb{Q}-Vect$ which commutes with $\otimes$, is exact and faithful.

The Betti-realization satisfy indeed $H_B((X,\Delta_X,0))=\bigoplus_{i=0}^{2\dim X}H^i(X,\mathbb{Q})$.

Now obviously, the group of automorphism of the functor $H_B$ will acts on $H_B(M)$. This is purely abstract non-sense, and does not give much informations. Of course, if we take only the subgroup of $\otimes$-automorphism of $H_B$, it will still acts on $H_B(M)$. Denote this group by $G_{mot}$ (the so-called motivic Galois group). So you have that, for any algebraic variety $X$, its cohomology $H^*(X)$ is a $G_{mot}$-representation.

So far, we only said trivialities (even if we assumed deep conjectures...), and we have absolutely no idea what $G_{mot}$ is !

But we have that the functor $H_B$ factor through the category of $G_{mot}$ representations. It happens that this is an equivalence of categories ! Now, this is still not a deep fact (but not a triviality neither). This is purely categorical : it does not use anything from algebraic geometry, nor what the category of motives is, nor what $H_B$ is...

So we can still say that we know nothing about $G_{mot}$ and its representation on $H^*(X)$. And we can't say much more...

---

Ok so before I say more, lets have a a new look at Galois theory. Consider only the motives of $0$-dimensional varieties. This will be a subcategory $AM(k)\subset M(k)$ (the category of so called Artin motives). A motive will essentially be the data of a finite reduced $k$-algebra $A$ and its realization $H_B(A)$ is the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space spanned by the $Hom_{k-alg}(A,\mathbb{C})$. Because $A$ is a finite over $k$, a morphism $A\to\mathbb{C}$ factor through $\overline{k}\subset\mathbb{C}$. So $Hom_{k-alg}(A,\mathbb{C})=Hom_{k-alg}(A,\overline{k})$. Obviously, $Gal(\overline{k}/k)$ acts on this set (by composition), and so we have a representation of $Gal(\overline{k}/k)$ on $H_B(A)=\mathbb{Q}.Hom_{k-alg}(A,\overline{k})$.

This is not hard to see that this action is natural in $A$. In other words, $Gal(\overline{k}/k)$ really acts on the functor $H_B$ (and by $\otimes$-automorphism). So we have a map $Gal(\overline{k}/k)\to Aut_\otimes(H_B)$.

It turns out that this is an isomorphism !

By Tannakian reconstruction, the category of Artin motives is equivalent to the category of representation of the Galois group.

---

Now what can we say if we consider the whole category of motives. Well not much. Though, every natural action of a group on every $H^*(X)$ will contributes to the motivic Galois group. For example, we can let $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ acts on $H^*(X)$ by $\lambda.x=\lambda^{\deg x} x$. This will be a natural action because every morphism $X\to Y$ preserve the degree of cohomology classes. We thus have a morphism $\mathbb{G}_m\to G_{mot}$ (this is called the weight-cocharacter).

The Galois group does not define a natural action anymore, this is because an element of $Gal(\overline{k}/k)$ does not induce a continuous map $X(\mathbb{C})\to X(\mathbb{C})$ and so does not induce a map in cohomology. I believe however that $Gal(\overline{k}/k)$ is supposed to be $\pi_0(G_{mot})=G_{mot}/G_{mot}^0$ (the group of connected components) but I am not sure about that.

---

In conclusion : I like to think of a motive as the finest structure we can put on the cohomology of algebraic varieties. These structures can be encoded in the action of a group (like the cohomological degree can be encoded by the action of $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ as I did previously). Every structure will contribute to the motivic Galois group (for example, we can put an Hodge structure on $H^*$, and so we will have a map from the Mumford-Tate group to the motivic Galois group.)

So asking what is the representation of the motivic Galois group, is not really possible without a much much much.... deeper understanding of the cohomology of algebraic varieties (and will probably require a huge amount of time).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that all the categorical abstract nonsense would become more transparent if we consider some special cases, but you seem to say this is not the case?

Comment: @Régis You said you want to understand the representation $\rho$ on $H^*(X)$. But the representation of which group ? As I said, this group has a very abstract definition (which requires deep conjectures). So we know (almost) nothing about $G$. So we can't say much about the representation itself. As I said, the representation is the finest structure we can put on the cohomology of an algebraic variety. By finest, I mean "all of them". So for example on the cohomology $H^*(E)$ on an elliptic curve, what kind of structure there is ? There is the graduation by degree. Are there others ? Yes...

Comment: I understand your point. I hoped (maybe very naively) that in the same way that in some cases representations of the absolute Galois group factor through the Galois group of a finite extension, which as a group is much simpler, something similar would happen with motives. Since it's not the case, I guess I have to understand the construction of the motivic Galois group, and as I said, I don't understand the abstract construction, partly because I miss some definitions and I don't know where to look for them.

Comment: To begin with, I don't know exactly what the Betti realization is, nor $\otimes$-automorphism functors.

Comment: Yes, the motivic Galois group acts on $H^*(X)$ through a quotient, even a small one ! This does not mean that we know more about it. The Betti realization is just the singular cohomology of complex points. A $\otimes$-automorphism of a monoidal functor $F$ is an natural automorphism $F\to F$ which is compatible with the natural isomorphism $F(A\otimes B)\simeq F(A)\otimes F(B)$.

Comment: Ok this becomes clearer to me. So to understand automorphisms of $H_B$ I suppose one should begin with understanding automorphisms of motives... Very roughly, my intuition is that automorphisms of the motive $(X,e,m)$ should be all the correspondances on $X$ which induce algebraic automorphisms on the cycles of codimension $m$, up to the idempotent $e$, but I am really not sure about that...

Comment: No, automorphisms of $H_B$ are not related to automorphism of motives : automorphisms of motives will not induce a natural transformation $H_B\to H_B$. Say you have a map $M(X)\to M(X)$, how does this gives a map $H^*(Y)\to H^*(Y)$ for *another* $Y\neq X$ ? But yes, automorphism of $(X,e,m)$ can be expressed as some group of cycles (though, this does not depend on $m$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88052/discussion-between-roland-and-regis).